# Sending message from a personal mail server

Tags: email, gmail

I configured a mail server on my LAN with windows server 2003(learning purposes) made some user accounts for other systems in LAN and all worked fine.

But then i tried to use it externally. so got a domain name , forwarded the port on the router for smtp and pop3 and when i tried to send mail to my gmail account and from gmail to my mail server i couldn't get by either way. I've tried several things but couldn't, can anyone explain am i missing something or should i use any other mail server.

Comment: Email is transmitted using SMTP protocol with TCP/IP port 25. Due historical reasons, most ISPs block *all traffic* from normal end user subscriber connections to any remote server port 25 and as such, you probably cannot send any email without ISP support. Your ISP should provide SMTP relay host that you can use and you have to ask the ISP about the possible authentication for that relay. My ISP allows sending email without authentication from its customer IP address space but limits the possible string you can use as `From` address.

Answer (score 0):

You have to forward smtp mail to your isp's smtp server.  You should have a setting in your mail server config for this.   But you do have to be careful spammers don't use your smtp server for spam - so you will need to secure your mail server.

Just to get you started, and especially as you indicate it is a learning project, first of all just get your smtp server forwarding to your ISP smtp server.  Usually something like mail.ispname.com

Then check you can send.

You can use smtp commands to interact with your mail server.

Example.

```
telnet 192.168.7.55 25
Trying 192.168.7.55...
Connected to 192.168.7.55.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 yourdomain.com ESMTP (Code-Crafters Ability Mail Server 2.6
HELO yourdomain.com
250 yourdomain.com
MAIL FROM: joe@yourdomain.com
250 Email address accepted. <joe@yourdomain.com>
RCPT TO: joe@gmail.com
250 Email address accepted. <jo@gmail.com>
DATA
354 Please send the data and end with a <CRLF>.<CRLF>.
Hi Guys

.
250 Mail accepted and queued for delivery.
quit
221 Thank you and good bye.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

This all assumes you have domain names setup.

for receiving, your smtp server must be accessible from your ISP's smtp server.  Usually you also have to specify that you want an smtp mail feed to get smtp mail delivered to your mail server.  Usually, for cheap end ISP deals you will only get pop3 mail delivery - where you say my pop3 mail account is joebloggs and they send all mail to joebloggs@theisp.com to that mailbox.

Setting up a mail server, particularly securing it is not trivial.

Comment: thanks, i will try to do it as you said, beside this i read about a thing that is blacklisting these kind of mail servers, can you also shed light on this.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to comment on that.